# Buttons unresponsive when microphone and speaker playing

Tags: ios, react-native, touchableopacity

I have a react native app that runs a native platform SDK which uses the microphone and speaker on the phone. When I start the sdk, it begins to play from the speaker and record from the microphone, but it doesn't start for about 30 seconds. During the 30 seconds between when I start the sdk and before the sdk actually starts playing/recording, all the buttons are responsive. However, as soon as the sdk starts playing/recording, all buttons (except for a slider) are unresponsive. The console logs say "touches began", and console logs that should be printed from the proceed method are not printed. In other words, it does not look like the proceed method is invoked at all when the button is pressed.

The SDK does not run on the main thread.

I have bound the proceed method to the class instance in the constructor.

Can anyone tell me why this is? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have managed to get the screen to respond by setting the onStartShouldSetResponder prop in a View component in the button to my proceed function but this is not a long term solution.